# Invoking context function not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of a context from a child Component but the context function is not being invoked.

To set the scene. Here is some example snippet data passed to handleModal in Dashboard.jsx

```
{
_id: "123", 
name: "test name", 
details: test details, 
content: "test content"
}
```

### SnippetContext.js

The `handleSnippetUpdate` function **should be getting invoked** from within Dashboard.jsx. **It is not.**

```
  state = {
    name: '',
    details: '',
    content: '',
  }

  handleSnippetUpdate = edit => event => {
    console.log('invoked') //does not get invoked
    this.setState({
      name: edit.name,
      details: edit.details,
      content: edit.content,
    })
  }
```

### Dashboard.jsx

Button invokes `handleModal` and passes in the snippet data.

`<button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleModal(snippet)}>Edit</button>`

```
  handleModal = snippet => {
    console.log(snippet) //snippet data correctly arrives in the function

    this.context.handleSnippetUpdate(snippet) 
    //DOES NOT WORK - need to know why and/or how to do correctly
    //should pass snippet data to handleSnippetUpdate function



    this.showModal.current.showModal() 
    //IGNORE - Runs a function in modal component which sets its state to true

  }
```

Comment: handleSnippetUpdate(something) returns a function that expects an event to be passed, when you pass the event the function will set state

Comment: The `event =>` in your handler definition makes no sense the way you use it. It should probably just take the `edit` as an argument. As it is it returns a function that takes an `event` as @HMR already pointed out. So it actually creates a handler rather than handling something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `event =>` from `handleSnippetUpdate` has fixed the issue.
As pointed out by HMR and trixn in the comments.

```
 handleSnippetUpdate = edit => event => {
    console.log('invoked') //does not get invoked
    this.setState({
      name: edit.name,
      details: edit.details,
      content: edit.content,
    })
  }
```